# Use of "until" and "the office" in emails

Tags: email

I am from a non-English speaking country. I work for a company which consists of wide range of foreign clients. Recently, I have been in the hot water with my boss over use of until and "the" before office in emails.

I have studied English translation and never encountered such argument.  Is he right that use of "until" in the email, indicates a period of one week? and we usually do not use the before the word office? as in the following sentence:

> Please kindly be informed that Mr. X is not currently at the office and is attending a training course until Wednesday 15 March.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **[about]** language specific details that are relevant for ELU.SE / ELL.SE sites

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/ would be a better SE for the question.

Comment: @Zhinus - I don't see anything wrong with the sentence. I would have phrased it 'in the office' rather than 'at the office', but the sentence as composed answers the question of whether or why Mr. X will not be responding until 15 March.

Comment: oOt putting the word 'the" before office would be incorrect. Your use of until is fine. However, if your boss doesn't like the structure, then just use the wording he prefers, this is not a big enough issue to be worth getting into a fight about. Save your "boss disagreement points" for really important things.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where "one week" fits in.  What is your boss saying the correct usage is?  I agree that this should be migrated to ELL, but it needs to be clarified first or they'll just close it as unclear.  After you [edit], please flag and request migration.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst this is better suited at ell.stackexchange.com I'll answer for you.

No, until does not designate a period of a week. It doesn't designate any time period but works in conjunction with a period of time to indicate up to that point of time. How you used it in your example above is perfectly fine. It states that Mr X will be back in work on the 15th March.

The only other point is that we say we are **in** the office, rather than **at** the office. Using at in that way is for past tense, e.g. *I was at the office this past weekend.*